# Python - Is there a way to add an "as" alias to a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, python-itertools

Note: `python --version` yields `Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.`

I'm working with some `itertools` code that seems pretty intent on putting out tuples, but I want to loop over each result as a `numpy.array`. Use case: Have a data set with ~10 features and I'm curious about brute-forcing all feature set combinations for a clustering fit.

So I tried this:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
import numpy as np
def the_python_way(value_list):
    # creates a generator on an iterator; not sure which
    def powerset(iterable):
        # Note: Seems to forcefully make the results tuples. Casting the tuple 
        # produced by combinations(...) to something else seems to alter the 
        # production order a bit, but when I check the type produced by the 
        # final chain.from_iterable(...) it still says "tuple". Weird.
        return chain.from_iterable(
                np.array(combinations(iterable, len_n))
                for len_n in range(len(iterable)+1))

    for item in powerset(value_list):
        print("type: ", type(item), ", item: ", np.array(item))

the_python_way([1,2,3])
```

Output:

```
type:  <class 'tuple'> , item:  ()
type:  <class 'tuple'> , item:  (1,)
type:  <class 'tuple'> , item:  (2,)
type:  <class 'tuple'> , item:  (3,)
type:  <class 'tuple'> , item:  (1, 2)
type:  <class 'tuple'> , item:  (1, 3)
type:  <class 'tuple'> , item:  (2, 3)
type:  <class 'tuple'> , item:  (1, 2, 3)
```

Huh. I could just override the loop value:

```
# attempt 1: just cast to np.array(item)
for item in powerset(value_list):
    item = np.array(item)
    # carry on
```

But that seems a little too C. Here's what I'd like to do:

```
# attempt 2: syntax error
for np.array(value) as item in powerset(value_list):
    # carry on
```

Not as preferable, but I'd hoped this might work. Nope:

```
# attempt 5: syntax error
for np.array(value) in powerset(value_list) as item:
    # carry on
```

**Is there a way to 'as' in a for loop?**

My google searches haven't turned up any questions about this on stackoverflow, but I'd be surprised if I was the first person to actually ask. Maybe I didn't search with the right keywords.

I've read [this w3schools entry on 'as'](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_as.asp), but it doesn't say anything about use in a for loop. If it isn't on w3schools, I'm guessing that this isn't a thing that Python can do, but I wanted to check stackoverflow anyway.

Comment: No there isn't. Just use `np.array`, that is the normal way anyone would do it. If you really want, wrap it in a `map(np.array, ...)` so `map(np.array, powerset(value_list))`

Comment: No one else has commented or answered, so would you repost this as an answer so I can flag it as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**

Answering for self: No one has offered an "answer" except via a comment, so reposting essence of comment in order to flag OP "answered".